# Multiple Currencies - Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, tracking, google-tag-manager, data-layers

We have a website that make use of multi-currencies for payments. But of course we don't want to show Australian Dollar the same as American Dollar. What is the work around for this?

We make use Google Tag Manager to push the values of ecommerce through the dataLayer.

I found this method (solution) - any comments on whether this is the best solution - http://blog.everymundo.com/set-up-multi-currency-in-google-analytics-using-google-tag-manager/

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite clear what you are asking (you seem to have figured things out already), but basically you set your base currency in the account, send along the local currency in the GA tracking call and if your local currency is in the list of supported currencies it will be converted to your base currency.

Here are the instructions on how to set the local currency in code:https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce#multicurrency

Complete list of supported currencies is here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6205902?hl=en

And specifically for the tag manager, yes, you would have to pass that in via the dataLayer. There is no field you can set to specify local currency via the interface.